# Exercises with solutions on Arithmetic Geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, book-recommendation, topological-groups, arithmetic-geometry

I am learning some basic arithmetic geometry and following the book "An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry" by Lorenzini. So, I am new to the subject and not sure whether the examples I consider or the way I am thinking is correct or not. Can you suggest me some textbook/lecture notes which has excessive amount of exercises?

Comment: Hindry and Silverman's book Diophantine Geometry: An introduction is quite good.

Comment: I've added the book-recommendation tag. The reference-question tag would fit too if you're okay with dropping one of the other tags.

Comment: Did you mean to write "extensive" or "copious" or some other synonym, rather than "excessive"? The latter word carries a negative overtone.

Comment: I am not sure what I meant back then, but extensive would be okay I guess :)